# Google Analytics - Variables not recording

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the following code:

```
if (_gaq){
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, "Selected States", state_list, 3]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, "Selected Months", month_list, 3]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, "Selected Programs", program_list, 3]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, "Zip code", zip_code, 3]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', "Schedule", "search", "", true]);
}
```

However, I can not find where they are being recorded. I created a custom report but am not sure if it is correct because nothing shows up on it.

Can someone help out here?

This should record every time a person is on my schedule page and every time the search variables change on the schedule page.

It seems now that even my event Schedule has stopped tracking, too.

Comment: @Joe, etc. Look, There are almost a HUNDRED other questions on SO about GA, Why do you say this is off-topic? Looks like you guys just enjoy being question-Nazi's to me. While you may think that this is about general computing and hardware, this is actually about PROGRAMMING.

Comment: I'm curious about the off-topic vote as well. It seems like this is a question related to non-obvious quirks in google-analytics. If it's off-topic because of the javascript tag, wouldn't it be more appropriate to just remove the tag?

Comment: It is javascript code, why would the javascript tag be off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a parameter, and `true` is getting passed as the integer `opt_value` parameter. `_trackEvent` can fail silently if a non-integer is passed for `opt_value`.

Custom variables only get recorded during something that makes a tracking pixel request like `_trackPageview` or `_trackEvent`. In your case, if `_trackEvent` fails, then any custom variables you set are ignored.

Try

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', "Schedule", "search", undefined, 0, true])
```

Comment: The EVENT isn't really what I'm after, the VARIABLES aren't getting set at all.

Comment: If the event isn't recorded, then the custom variables will be ignored.

Comment: While the _trackEvent action is defined like this: 

    `_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)`

The javascript code to push it looks like this:

    `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Pause', 'Gone With the Wind']);`

Comment: Looks like you were correct. I was getting an error before and that caused the values to not be stored.